# airflow cannot detect dag file for my course project

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have been trying to create a new dag file, however things like `airflow dags list` or `airflow webserver --port 8080` doesn't detect the said file.

I have based my dag file from a `example_python_operator.py`, I have created a new admin user for this.  It is placed in `~/airflow`. `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow` command was executed.

#### my dag file

```
import logging
import shutil
import time
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

with DAG(
    dag_id='download_publications_data_dag',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['example_dag'],
) as dag:
    pass
```

even without the pass keyword and the original code it doesn't work.

I already kill and pkill every process relating to airflow via `ps aux | grep airflow` and `lsof -i 0.0.0.0:8080`

My professor suggested to use cloud version but I rather be it on my local computer

Is this because of my conda environment?
Any suggestions for solution for this problem?

Edit: `python3 download_publications_data_dag.py` shows no error

Edit: downgraded to python3.9, reinstalled airflow but still no detection

Comment: where is your dag.py file. Have specify airflow config file to check for the correct directory?

Comment: it is in ~/airflow/dags and I have `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow`

Comment: try to put absolute path. also in airflow.cfg check the "dag_folder" value (under core scetion)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad answer but somehow from my fiddling my airflow detected my dag file. However I do not 100% recall the step for this as I was trying out an `aws` method.

I think it may be something to do with

1. deleting `~/airflow`
2. reinstalling airflow
3. creating `~/airflow/dags` and putting my dag file in it
4. `airflow db init`
5. `airflow dags list` or `airflow webserver port -8080` to verify airflow's detection of the dag file